# Web data connector with server

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, tableau-api

I'm trying to load in Tableau some data from a JSON. 
I have the URL for this JSON. If I try to access directly to this URL the JSON is created and I can download it (takes me 15 seconds).
In order to load this data, I'm using a web data connector, the jsonConnector.html in the Example folder. 
This is my architecture:

```
My computer    ||    Server
Tableu        :81    Connector
              :9000  JSON URL
```

So I'm using putty and port forwarding actually. 
On the port 81, I can access to the connector from my PC to the server. 
On the port 9000, I have a website which provides a URL for the JSON

What I do it's to go in tableau -> Web data connector -> http://localhost:81/Examples/jsonConnector.html -> url for json : http://localhost:9000/MYURLFORJSON -> submit
Then a pop-up arrives : Loading metadata...
I let the process run for 10 hours now... I think it's not working.

Is there a way to have some debugging? Is it a problem with my architecture?

**[UPDATE]**
If I drag and drop my JSON file it works! So I need to understand why I can't reach the server passing the URL to the connector. 
I Don't know how I could have some debug information

Answer (score 0):

Finally put my connector on port 9000 into the web service and it works.
It was a problem of port forwarding.